# Generating Report from User Inputs in Access Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, reporting

Goal: To create an access form that takes user inputs combines those with a bound value in an access query calculates a final number and then generates a report.

The only issue I am having here in referencing the user inputs on the form to the actual report.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the report it would be:

```
=Forms!YourUserInputFormName!txtUserInputBox
```

The form must be left open.

Answer (score 0):

Design your query so that the field to filter by is just a data field, then use the `WhereCondition` parameter of `OpenReport`.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName",acViewNormal,,"My field=" & Me.txtUserInput
```

Variation for text field and Preview instead of Print:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName",acViewPreview,,"My field='" & Me.txtUserInput & "'"
```